# Formulating pricing optimization as MILP

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am uncertain whether it is possible to formulate the following problem in a linear fashion or whether i should attempt to optimize it non-linearly.

I wish to find the optimal combination of a fixed fee `F` and variable price `p` for a product.

I have a given number of `n` clients who each want to purchase quantity `q_i` for which they are willing to pay a total price of  `w_i`.

My objective is to maximize revenue: `max sum( F + q_i * p)` for all customers `i in n`

My decision variables are of course `F` and `p` and then n binary variables `s_i` indicating whether a customer is buying or not.

I am having trouble formulating this problem and the constraints in a way to allow for customers not purchasing - some customers have a very low willingness to pay.

There is obviously the constraint `F + q_i * p <= w_i` but this only holds for the customers buying. I would like to impose something like `s_i * (F + q_i * p) <= w_i`but this is clealy not linear.

I hope the above makes sense, and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This is called a "fixed charge problem". This is a well-known problem. Standard formulations can be found using Google.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I might very well be wrong, but as i understand the fixed charge problem, it is about minimizing the cost of the sum of some known fixed and veriable 'charges' - typically cost of producing or transporting. In my case the 'charge' itself is a decision variable, the price has to be determined to optimize revenue in my case.

Comment: why not use [NLP with gekko](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/NonlinearPricing)

Comment: for MILP [here formulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64574862/15893581)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try again.

We can state the problem as:

```
 max sum(i,  s(i)*(F+p*q(i))) 
     s(i)*(F+p*q(i)) ≤ w(i)
     for variables s(i) ∈ {0,1}, p ≥ 0, F ≥ 0
```

This can be linearized as:

```
 max sum(i, y(i))
     y(i) ≤ F+p*q(i)
     y(i) ≤ s(i)*w(i)
     y(i) ≥ F+p*q(i) - (1-s(i))*M
     for variables s(i) ∈ {0,1}, p ≥ 0, F ≥ 0, y(i) ≥ 0
     with M a large enough constant
```

Many solvers allow indicator constraints. This will simplify things:

```
 max sum(i, y(i))
     s(i) = 1 ==> y(i) = F+p*q(i)
     y(i) ≤ s(i)*w(i)  
     for variables s(i) ∈ {0,1}, p ≥ 0, F ≥ 0, y(i) ≥ 0
```

or using two indicator constraints::

```
 max sum(i, y(i))
     s(i) = 1 ==> y(i) = F+p*q(i)
     s(i) = 0 ==> y(i) = 0
     for variables s(i) ∈ {0,1}, p ≥ 0, F ≥ 0, y(i) ∈ [0,w(i)]
```